# How to convert AnsiStr to Bytes and vice versa?

Tags: string, byte, pascal, lazarus

Hope somebody can help me with this problem - I have to read data from an interface that is specified like this:

<Each message consists of a 2-byte length (in network byte order) followed by that many bytes of data. The end of the msg series is indicated by an empty message (length of 0).>

Using TDataPortTCP  I can read the buffer with Dataport.Peek(size) and pull the data from the buffer with Dataport.Pull(size) - both methods provide the result as AnsiStr

I imagine that something like this should work, but I have no idea how to convert AnsiStr to Bytes and vice versa:

```
   while DataPortTCP.Peek(2) > ZeroBytes do
   begin
      LengthInBytes := DataPortTCP.Pull(2) ;
      sContent := DataPortTCP.Pull(LengthInByte) ;
   end;
```

How do I declare / get / convert ZeroBytes and LengthInBytes and how do I have to deal with Endianess ?

Unfortunately I know nothing about TBytes and what I read so far did only lead to more confusion ;-)

I would be very grateful if someone could point me into the right direction.

Comment: You need to know what the text encoding is

Comment: The data received is in Standard ASCII, DataPortTCP provides the data as ANSI String

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a string is not empty, you can compare to `''`.

To retrieve the byte value from a string, you can access the character and apply the `ord` function.

Network order is big endian, mean that the first byte is of higher order. Hence you need to shift it to the left using `shl`. In this case, there are two bytes, so the first on is shifted 8 bits, which amounts to multiplying it by 256.

```
var
  LengthInBytesStr: String;
  LengthInBytes: Word;

begin
  ...
  while DataPortTCP.Peek(2) <> '' do
  begin
    LengthInBytesStr := DataPortTCP.Pull(2);
    LengthInBytes := (ord(LengthInBytesStr[1]) shl 8)
                   + ord(LengthInBytesStr[2]);

    sContent := DataPortTCP.Pull(LengthInByte);
  end;
```